# Passing a variable to a method to initialize it fails

Tags: android

In the code below I pass a null generic ArrayAdapter to a method where it should initialize it and add items to it, but it doesn't, is it because Java passes variables by value?

I can overcome this issue by returning the ArrayAdapter and assign it to my variable, but what if I want to initialize more than one variable using the same method at one call to this method?

```
ItemsList(mList, mAdapter);

private void ItemsList(final List<ItemDetails> aList, ArrayAdapter<ItemDetails> aAdapter){


    aAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<ItemDetails>(this, R.layout.item, aList) {
        @Override
        @NonNull
        public View getView(int aPosition, View aConvertView, @NonNull ViewGroup aParent) {
            return getView(aPosition, aConvertView, aParent, aList);
        }
    };

    gridViewList.setAdapter(aAdapter);

    aAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Oops.. sleepy eyes. Yes, because Java is "call by value [of the reference]", assigning to the parameter does *not* update the variable in the caller. Generally, a good/simple/customary method is to pass values/objects *inward*, eg. `ItemsList(mList, CreateAdapter())` or whatnot.

Comment: Here's my situation, I use 4 array adapters, so instead of created / cloning the same method for each one of them, I considered passing the arrayadapter to the method, which is more flixable in future changes. even using your approach requries atleast to pass an integer and using switch to decide which adapter to create which means more lines of codes.

Comment: As per method purpose it should return ArrayAdapter but you mentioned that you want to initialise more variable in same method call . Can you elaborate the situation?

Comment: @Jack Not sure why it'd be more lines of code.. where does "an integer" come from? I don't see such in the posted code, so it doesn't seam like such would be required externally either. In my first comment, also note that `CreateAdapter` is a method, hiding (and possibly re-using) implementation details.